# Redirecting UTM to Original URL

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, urchin

This question was asked once and was closed without asking. I am going to ask again with more clarity in hopes to get answer for the community.

When using UTM tracking to track various campaigns in Google Analytics the following issue surfaces:

- If someone bookmarks a URL tagged with UTM that indicates it comes from another marketing channel...social and email are great examples.

The desire to redirect the UTM URL to original in this case makes sense....kinda. I mean some people would want to know that the bookmark visits first originated from the campaign.

However some website owners do not and would prefer that the Bookmarked URL is the original URL.

All of this make sense?

Please let me know if I need to clarify further.

Comment: I added close question here - http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/97793/how-utm-long-urls-for-the-homepage-of-project-influence-on-user-experience